# Can I somehow get arguments passed to function in LLVM IR?

Tags: llvm

I want to move function call to other place in program, but i have a problem with arguments. I need get object associated with argument value.

```
Function *fu;

bool runOnModule(Module &M) override {
  for(Function &a : M){
      for(BasicBlock &b : a){
        for(Instruction &i : b){
          if(isa<CallInst>(i)){
            fu = cast<CallInst>(i).getCalledFunction();
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
  moveToOtherFunc(fu);
  return true;
}

void moveToOtherFunc(Function *f){
   ...
   BasicBlock *bb = ...
   ...

   //now i must insert a arg object ( ArrayRef<Value*> arg )
   //it is a list of objects representing func arguments 
   CallInst::Create(f,arg,"",bb);
}
```

So is there some function, that give me a list of arguments? Something like:

```
ArgumentsValueList a = f->getArgumentsValueObjectsAssociatedWithThisFunction();
```

I now that there is a `Function::arg_iterator`, but this give me just information about type and number of arguments, but no a object holding a value of argument, right? What i need to do, so i move call inst with arguments? Thanks

Comment: What do you expect to happen if the arguments are non-constant locals computed in the original function?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [`args()`](http://llvm.org/doxygen/classllvm_1_1Function.html#a0b44832d4b6bb57b0e8c61fc3242547b) method in the `Function` class for your purpose.

It returns a pair of iterators for the start and the end of the argument list, through which you can iterate over all the arguments.

Comment: Yes it return `iterator_range< arg_iterator >` , but when i want to Create CallInst in other function with this arguments it give me a error. `Referring to an argument in another function!
  %_Z3subii = call i32 @_Z3subii(i32 %a, i32 %b)`